# Some plugin to see database Sqlite in a application with apache cordova on browser?

Tags: android, apache, sqlite, cordova

I am new with apache cordova and I try do a application ApacheCordova with SQlite using this plugin :
[Cordova-sqlite-storage](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage)

But this plugin not work in a browser. Exist some plugin that allow execute my app in a browser and  can see my database in the browser(or some adminsitrator SQLite) ???

I don't want to compile my application on a device. while i am developing.
The app will be compiled in Android, IOS, Windows Phone.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of sqlitebrowser to view contents of sqlite
You can also make use of webSQL API .The interface remains same whtehter you use webSQL or sqlLite.

I have used WebSQL.(its depricated though)
[DB Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/)